# Custom Google Search redirects to https://cse.google.com/cse/all

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search

Hi I'm using custom google search for my website but when I search it just redirects to https://cse.google.com/cse/all. I'm inserting the generated public URL onto the action part of the form tag. When copying and pasting the URL on the browser the search does work. Thanks!

This is my HTML code:

```
<form method = "get" title = "Search Form" action="https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=001331330360923127228:ghn4eoirwti">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" value="Search" title="Search this site" alt="Search Text" maxlength="256"/>
    <input type="image" id="searchSubmit" name="submit" src="http://webresource.its.calpoly.edu/cpwebtemplate/5.0.0/common/images_html/header/search-arrow.png" alt="Go" title="Submit Search Query" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass a parameter (cx) inside the action URL; so the return is missing your cx parameter and moves to the new parameter passed (q). The code below places your cx value in a hidden field to be passed along with the q parameter; give this a try:

```
<form method = "get" title = "Search Form" action="https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" value="Search" title="Search this site" alt="Search Text" maxlength="256"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="cx" name="cx" value="001331330360923127228:ghn4eoirwti">
    <input type="image" id="searchSubmit" name="submit" src="http://webresource.its.calpoly.edu/cpwebtemplate/5.0.0/common/images_html/header/search-arrow.png" alt="Go" title="Submit Search Query" />
  </div>
</form>
```